# Too Many Redirect Error in PHP

Tags: php

In my php script I am using two `header();` functions, one is ->

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'];) {
header('Location: locationtologin');
exit;
}
```

And other is to check if the user has specified a URL (checking via MySQL).

When I try to visit the page, it says

`The 52.76.198.25 page isn’t working`

```
52.76.198.25 redirected you too many times.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

What is going wrong? Can anybody help me please!

Thanks.

Comment: Probably your "locationtologin" make a redirection too. So the page redirect in loop. Check your conditions :)

Comment: What headers are there on locationtologin?

Comment: Put exit on very first line of the page "locationtologin" and check if issue still persist then there is other issue and if page is not redirecting in loop then your "locationtologin" page is again redirecting you.

Comment: @spudmonkee there are a total of 5 `header('Location'); in my login php so maybe that would be an error, any way I'll remove the check if user is logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the locationtologin page also redirects you to a page that also redirects you to page that also redirects you to a page etc.. You are stuck in a redirect loop and therefore he is complaining about too many redirects. Try to remove the redirect on the locationtologin page.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a closing bracket:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'];) {
```

change to:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
```

Not sure if this will solve your answer but its still incorrect syntax.

Comment: I just typed it so maybe a typo, I didn't copy-pasted the original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: anotherpage.php'); // don't redirect same page
    exit();
}
```

use this.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.